# Extract part in JSON file and create Pandas dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe

I am fairly new to python and especially wrt JSON files. I am trying to create a dataframe, and have already searched for information but I keep getting errors and I am just not getting on the right track with it.

I want to put in a part of a JSON file into a dataframe. The dataframe (3 specific columns from the json only) should look like:

SECS  WATTS  CAD
0     291    93
1     349    96
2     478    98
3     etc    etc.

I have data stored in 1 JSON FILE (called train.json). see how it looks like below.

Apology if this is an easy question, but I am just not getting on the right track for it. Any help is welcome which can put me on the right track with this. Sorry if the format of this question is not what it should be. First time I ask a question here.

```
{
    "RIDE":{
        "STARTTIME":"2017\/09\/09 14:30:32 UTC ",
        "RECINTSECS":1,
        "DEVICETYPE":"SRM PC8 ",
        "IDENTIFIER":" ",
        "OVERRIDES":[
            { "total_distance":{ "value":"108.9" }}
        ],
        "TAGS":{
            "Aerobic TISS":"0 ",
            "Anaerobic TISS":"0 ",
            "Athlete":"Ruud Goorden ",
            "Average Cadence":"0 ",
            "Average Heart Rate":"0 ",
            "Daniels EqP":"0 ",
            "Daniels Points":"0 ",
            "Data":"T--PHC-AG--EV-- ",
            "Device":"SRM PC8 ",
            "Device Info":" "
        },
        "SAMPLES":[
            { "SECS":0, "WATTS":291, "CAD":93, "HR":122, "ALT":-5, "LAT":51.472068788, "LON":3.8169967494, "TEMP":23, "LRBALANCE":45 },
            { "SECS":1, "WATTS":349, "CAD":96, "HR":121, "ALT":-4, "LAT":51.472003912, "LON":3.8171036187, "TEMP":23, "LRBALANCE":44 },
            { "SECS":2, "WATTS":478, "CAD":98, "HR":124, "ALT":-5, "LAT":51.471939036, "LON":3.8172316103, "TEMP":23, "LRBALANCE":44 },
            { "SECS":3, "WATTS":286, "CAD":95, "HR":125, "ALT":-5, "LAT":51.471866617, "LON":3.8173634577, "TEMP":23, "LRBALANCE":45 }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. New to editing. The data next to the SEC WATTS and CAD should of course be under those headers. Don't now how to properly show that

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_json()`?

Comment: Hi John. Yes have tried. filet=pd.read_json('train.json',orient='columns'). Also tried other orients but get ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Got it working. DataFrame is a mess but with some editing I will be OK.  with open('train.json', 'r') as f:
    c = f.readlines()
 
df=pd.DataFrame(c)

Comment: Yeah that's not a very pretty DataFrame is it?  I've added an answer using `json_normalize` to structure the data more cleanly.

Comment: Hi John. Correct. This is not a nice dataframe ;). I will try your solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_json()` will give you:

```
                                                         RIDE
DEVICETYPE                                           SRM PC8 
IDENTIFIER                                                   
OVERRIDES            [{'total_distance': {'value': '108.9'}}]
RECINTSECS                                                  1
SAMPLES     [{'SECS': 0, 'WATTS': 291, 'CAD': 93, 'HR': 12...
STARTTIME                            2017/09/09 14:30:32 UTC 
TAGS        {'Aerobic TISS': '0 ', 'Anaerobic TISS': '0 ',...
```

This is a DataFrame with a single column, and there are JSON documents inside each cell.  We need to crack open the cells which have compound values:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.RIDE.OVERRIDES)
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.RIDE.SAMPLES)
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.RIDE.TAGS).T # transpose for easy reading
```

Those give you:

```
  total_distance.value
0                108.9

---

   ALT  CAD   HR        LAT       LON  LRBALANCE  SECS  TEMP  WATTS
0   -5   93  122  51.472069  3.816997         45     0    23    291
1   -4   96  121  51.472004  3.817104         44     1    23    349
2   -5   98  124  51.471939  3.817232         44     2    23    478
3   -5   95  125  51.471867  3.817363         45     3    23    286

---
                                   0
Aerobic TISS                      0 
Anaerobic TISS                    0 
Athlete                Ruud Goorden 
Average Cadence                   0 
Average Heart Rate                0 
Daniels EqP                       0 
Daniels Points                    0 
Data                T--PHC-AG--EV-- 
Device                      SRM PC8 
Device Info
```

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: for some reason it already goes wrong with pd.read_json('train.json'). It gives ValueError: Expected object or value. Very strange so that's why I have a long (ugly procedure now)

Comment: with open('train.json', 'r') as f:
    c = f.readlines()
 #print(c)
 
df=pd.DataFrame(c)
#print(df)

#colom name
df.columns = ['veld']
#only relevant records 
df=df[df['veld'].str.contains("WATTS")]

from there I start to use 
df['secf'] = df.veld.str.split(':').str.get(1)
df['wattf'] = df.veld.str.split(':').str.get(2)
df['sec'] = df.secf.str.split(',').str.get(0)
df['watt'] = df.wattf.str.split(',').str.get(0)
df=df.drop(['veld','secf','wattf'],1)

#make numeric
df['sec'] = pd.to_numeric(df['sec'], errors='coerce')
df['watt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['watt'], errors='coerce')

Comment: @Ruud_G: I literally copy-pasted your example input into a file and used `read_json()` on it.  It works.  If it doesn't work for you, try with your example input from your question.  And if it still doesn't work, tell us your Pandas version.

Comment: Hi John. On the example it works. But for some reason it does not work on my original datafile. See below info on pd.show_versions(). Maybe I can send you the original file for which I made the example excerpt? I see you have the same hobby ;) (apart from bitcoins)

Comment: pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: 3.0.7
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.12.1
scipy: 0.19.0
xarray: None
IPython: 5.3.0
sphinx: 1.5.6
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.0
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.6.2
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.0.2
openpyxl: 2.4.7
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
lxml: 3.7.3
bs4: 4.6.0
html5lib: 0.999
sqlalchemy: 1.1.9
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.6
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None

Comment: Rather than trying to send me your input file, you should whittle it down until you have found that part that makes it fail.  If your sample input works but your real input doesn't, we can't do a lot about it until we see the specific part that trips up the Pandas parser.  Maybe part of your document is malformed--try https://jsonlint.com/ .

Comment: Yes. Strange thing is that when I copy paste my Json text from my file (from which the above was just a small excerpt) to Notepad and then save it as .json file your procedure works. So there must be something with the original json file for some reason (as said it does not do read_json, it gives ''ValueError: Expected object or value''. But copy and pasting and saving it as a new Json file does work. Very strange. When I start googling I end up in a swamp unfortunately.

Comment: And I am using Anaconda maybe that has something to do with it